# how does facebook ticker work, e.g on certain res or zoom it hides

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been trying to figure out how to make a ticker like facebook.

the ticker automatically hides when you zoom past 110% and thats because the ticker would start to cover the whole layout.

I was wondering how they have done this? how does it detect when to hide the ticker? does it grab the resolution in javascript?

Comment: Show some code of what you have tried?

Comment: at the moment it checks the resolution through javascript every 15 second interval and if its over a certain res it hides the div with jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever they are doing, it is done through Javascript.  You can get the width and height of the browser window and also any element in the DOM.

You can use pure Javascript, but jQuery makes this a doddle:

```
// Get the pixel width and height of the window
var window_height = $(window).height();  // not required, but for clarity
var window_width = $(window).width();
var ticker_width = $('div#ticker_wrapper').width();

// ON rezise, do something
$(window).resize(function() {

  // Do a caculation
  var new_width = (window_width/100)*10; // 10% width

  // Adjust the width of the ticker to suit
  $('div#ticker_width').css('width', new_height);

});
```

Comment: Glad to hear it's ok.  I just noticed and changed the typo for 'ticker', I spelled it as ticket' doh!